# Local variables in assembly:are they faster than global variables?

Tags: c++, winapi, masm

I was wondering if local variables in assembly are faster than the global variables that we use. The context for this is that I am learning some 2d animation using the win32 api, from a  book. The author uses a function to initialize(Creation,registration, showing and updating of the window) the main window for the program. I wrote that function in asm(just to practice some asm). So, I was wondering if there is any performance advantage involved, since in the asm function i used, the WNDCLASSEX structure was created locally(in stack). I know that the local variables in assembly are supposed to be faster, but having gone through the disassembly for another program(entirely in cpp), I noticed that the compiler creates the WNDCLASSEX locally as well. This confused me about the topic. So i want to know if there is any difference in performance between the asm code and C++ code.

Devjeet

Comment: Concepts of variable or scope (local, global) don't exist in assembly. And C++ is not defined in terms of assembly concepts.

Comment: No code. Hard to say which is faster. Irrelevant given the calls to CreateWindow etc. which swamp your code.

Comment: @cat I suppose that you could consider a variable residing on the stack as local and one allocated in data segment as global

Comment: @David: Except that local variables can be declared as `static`. Also, C++ has no notions of "stack" and "data segment", only "object lifetime" and "storage duration" :)

Comment: They do, using macaronis.  It isn't faster.  Usually slower because you don't have a machine finding ways to optimize them by storing them in a register.  Unlikely with a WNDCLASSEX though :)  What's with the glut of program-windows-in-assembly questions?  Indian school system?

Comment: @Fred Once you get to assembler, I think it's reasonable to talk about stacks.

Comment: The Win32 API is so incredibly painful. Why would you want to learn it in the first place? You will be a lot more productive by using SDL or SMFL or something like that.

Comment: @HansPassant
Not the indian school system. I live in Seattle btw. I am into game programming and some of the security stuff. So i took up ASM and C++

Comment: I was just wondering if there is any point in doing this stuff in assembly. I did not provide the code because I am not talking about the code and how the actual stuff is done. I am asking only whether variables on stack in assembly are faster than declaring a variable within a function in C++.

Comment: Absolutely no point whatsoever doing this in assembly.

Comment: Make it right before you make it fast. Global variables are harder to reason about. (Is it thread-safe? What about re-entrancy?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top of the stack is touched by a lot of code.  That means the the top of the stack is usually in CPU cache.  Accessing this would be faster than accessing other memory areas (from `.bss`, etc).

But for a function like `CreateWindow` which is called only a few times per program this doesn't really matter.  The difference is less than a a few hundred CPU cycles.  For other parts of the code the difference might be more noticeable.  But an important thing to note is that if you're doing the same thing repeatedly with the same piece of data that data too will end up in CPU cache and thus the performance difference would be negated.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I think you should leave such decisions to the compiler. The people who wrote the compiler have spent a lot of person-years optimizing the code, so there is very little reason to worry about such things for 99% of all apps. In the 1% case, when you compile, do an assembly listing and check the code, since there you may earn a cycle or two.

Answer (score 2):

Without having your code to judgment, i have an advise:

Some days, coding in assembly was a great way to write a fast program. But, nowadays with third-party libraries, complex algorithms, smart optimizations in compilers, portability issues and huge improvements in cpu and memory speeds, this approach is leaving off.

Even, in my experience hand made assembly codes may occurs bad effect on performance of code, because compilers can not make smart codes in that assembly block.

Another bad thing with coding with assembly inside a high level language is preventing portability a code.

*Note: Yet, there is some machines and systems which coding by assembly is good for them.*